# Get weekStart and weekEnd dynamically?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have spent so much time trying to figure out how this can be done but could not do it. So please help me out.

I have this data:

```
ID  employee_id     worked_date     start_time      finish_time
 1     1          2013-09-25        09:00:00    17:30:00
 2     1          2013-09-26        07:00:00    17:00:00
 8     1          2013-10-01        09:00:00    17:00:00
 9     1          2013-10-04        09:00:00    17:00:00
 12    1          2013-10-07        09:00:00    17:00:00
 13    1          2013-10-10        09:00:00    17:00:00
 14    1          2013-10-11        09:00:00    17:00:00
```

My first day of the week is Wednesday. The base date is 2013-09-25 which is Wednesday. I need to be able to get the weekStart and weekEnd dynamically. For example, based on the data I have above, there are three weeks between 2013-09-25 to 2013-10-11. I order my data with the latest worked_date first. If the user requested for week3, then the weekStart should be 2013-09-25 and weekEnd should be 2013-10-01. If the user requested for week2, then the weekStart should be 2013-10-02 to 2013-10-08 and so on.

The parameter week will be passed dynamically. Thanks for your help.

Here is the result I want to achieve when the requested week is 3:

```
ID  employee_id     worked_date     start_time      finish_time  weekStart    weekEnd
 1     1          2013-09-25        09:00:00    17:30:00        2013-09-25    2013-10-01
 2     1          2013-09-26        07:00:00    17:00:00        2013-09-25    2013-10-01
 8     1          2013-10-01        09:00:00    17:00:00        2013-09-25    2013-10-01
```

Using this query will give me the weekStart and weekEnd for each record

```
SELECT *, dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105') AS WeekStart , 
          dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105') + 6 AS WeekEnd 
FROM Timesheet
```

But I do not want this. I want only a particular week that the user requested.

Comment: Using this query will give me the weekStart and weekEnd for each record SELECT *
, dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105') AS WeekStart
, dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105')+6 AS WeekEnd
FROM Timesheet. But I do not want this. I want only a particular week that the user requested.

Comment: So how are you determining that 9-25-2013 the 3rd week when it's the fourth of the month?

Comment: It's the third week based on this query: WITH CTE AS (

     SELECT employee_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, ''20130925'', worked_date )/7 DESC) AS weekRank
     FROM Timesheet
     )

     SELECT TOP (1) weekRank  
     FROM CTE
     WHERE employee_id=@employee_id  
     ORDER BY weekRank DESC. I count backward to determine how many week this employee has worked so far since 2013-09-25.

Comment: Why can't the user just select a start date and then you add 7 days to the date they selected to get the week?

Comment: Because this is a payment system, my client needs to see each week for the number of hours an employee has worked. I am using a gridview and each page on the gridview represent each week. And the payment is paid weekly.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might need a calendar table.

```
create table calendar (
calendarId int identity(1,1) primary key,
year int,
month int,
week int,
startDate date,
endDate date)
```

then you could say 'give me all the records for week 2'

```
declare @week int = 2
declare @year int = 2013

;with employeeCalendar as (
  select
    employee.employeeid
   ,startDate
   ,endDate 
  from 
    employee 
  cross apply 
    calendar
  where 
    calendar.week = @week ) 
select
  employeeCalendar.EmployeeId
 ,employeeShift.[date]
 ,start_time
 ,finish_time
 ,startDate 
 ,endDate 
from
  employeeCalendar
left join
  employeeShift 
on employeeShift.employeeid = employeeCalendar.employeeid 
and employeeShift.worked_date 
between employeeCalendar.startDate and employeeCalendar.endDate
```

You could populate that table with a query like this:

```
;with calendarCte as (
select
  1 as week
 ,convert(date,'2013-09-25') as startDate
 ,convert(date,'2013-10-01') as endDate
 union all
 select
  week + 1
 ,dateadd(week,1,startDate)
 ,dateadd(week,1,endDate)
 from
  calendarCte 
 where
  calendarCte.startDate < convert(date,'2043-09-25') ) 
insert into calendar( [year],[month],[week],startdate,stopdate)
 select 
  datepart(year,startDate) as [year] 
 ,datepart(month,startDate) as [month]
 ,week as [week]
 ,startDate
 ,endDate
 from calendarCte option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Michael, how do I populate the table using '2013-09-25' to '2013-10-01' as the first week and loop for 30 years.

Comment: sorry it is my first time to populate table like this. Please show me a bit more how I can make use of the CTE above and populate it into the calendar table based on the table definition you suggested earlier.

Comment: @asplearning, first you'd want to create the calendar table. If you comment out the insert into statement it will just select what the result of the cte execution will be. When you're comfortable that it has the results you want, then uncomment the insert statement.

Comment: the Option (maxrecursion 0) helps me out. Sorry one more thing, if I would like to reset the weekCount for each year to 1. How can that be done? Thanks

Comment: @asplearning, you have two options. You could change 'week + 1' to case when [week] = 52 then 1 else [week] + 1 end OR you could not start with week 1 and instead start with datepart(iso_week,convert(date,'2013-09-25')) and then each subsequent week would be datepart(iso_week,dateadd(week,1,startDate)).

Comment: @asplearning, I have updated the query to return employee information when an employee has not worked during a week.

Answer (score 1):

You said you are looking for a stored procedure.  Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName @week int AS

SELECT * FROM Timesheet
WHERE worked_date >= dateadd(week, @week, '2013-09-25')
AND worked_date < dateadd(day,7,dateadd(week, @week, '2013-09-25'))
```

If you want your weekStart and weekEnd you could add them in to the SELECT as you did before.

If you want this in descending order from the current week backwards you could write it as follows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName @week int AS

SELECT * FROM Timesheet
WHERE worked_date >= dateadd(week, -@week, '2013-10-16')
AND worked_date < dateadd(day,7,dateadd(week, -@week, '2013-10-16'))
```

You could also parameterize the Date you are passing into the stored procedure as the current week will always be changing.

Comment: Hello Harrison, I am trying different options. Yours seem to work except one thing. I have a gridview with three pages representing 3 weeks order by worked_date DESC. That means latest record comes on first page. So if the user clicked on page 1, it is actually WHERE worked_date >= dateadd(week, 2, '2013-09-25')
AND worked_date < dateadd(day,7,dateadd(week, 2, '2013-09-25')). If the user clicked on page 3, it is actually WHERE worked_date >= dateadd(week, 0, '2013-09-25')
AND worked_date < dateadd(day,7,dateadd(week, 0, '2013-09-25'))

Comment: @asplearning, if you want to look at the week as the number of weeks back you can use dateadd to subtract from the current week.  the `@week` value would be negative and the Dates would then be whatever you are considering the current week.